# How do I push data onto multiple lines in a MySql table row?

Tags: mysql, formatting

I have a table containing user reviews. one of the fields is very long and I would like to display it over multiple lines so as to keep the formatting of the table nice.

For example, I would like to change:

```
    'This user was very helpful and friendly and I will definitely be using him again.'
```

To:

```
    'This user is very helpful and friendly and
     I will definitely be using him again.'
```

I have searched around and many queries involve splitting elements into many variables, whereas I wish to keep mine as one, just make it over two lines.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If using PHP, `nl2br()` and `br2nl()` maybe.

Comment: The answer to your question is dependent on what you are using to query your data: i.e. where are you outputting this to where you want it to be more readable?

Comment: This is not a database problem, this is a presentation problem. Doing this in MySQL is misguided. Whatever you're using to display this should assume the responsibility of breaking lines.

Comment: I think you'll need to have the <br> in the database, then parse it out afterwards using PHP `nl2br` for instance.